# Is ember.js stable enough to use in a real world project?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

I read that there api is unstable and might break. Just wanted to know if, as of today, the api is stable enough to be used.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of projects based on Ember.js - so if you're worried about actually being able to get something done I think your fear is unwarranted. [Check out their demo page.](http://emberwatch.com/#examples)
Discourse, some very large discussion software, is written on top of Ember.js. Ultimately, you won't know if the API is good enough until you try it yourself but larger sites have shipped products on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

### Of course!

Check [this podcast](http://emberhotseat.com/2013/07/19/ember-hot-seat-episode-007.html) which is an interview with Yehuda Katz (one of the creators of ember.js) that was recorde not long ago, it will give you some insight. Ember.js is about to reach **1.0**, so again, yes you can use it for real world projects, and many people are alredy doing it so you will not be alone.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have build a application using the version 1.0.pre. Very old, but worked without problems to me. So in my opinion ember is very stable. After each release, the changes are blogged in http://emberjs.com/blog/, so you can update your app, if needed. Just ember-data have warnings about your usage, so if you want to use it, be aware.